# Does Mad Max: Fury Road take place in dystopian Australia?

Tags: plot-explanation, mad-max-fury-road

Well, the title is self explanatory.
The first three mad max movies take place in dystopian Australia as it is specifically mentioned [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079501/). But in Fury Road, I haven't seen any specific mention about where it takes place.
So does it take place in dystopian Australia? If not, where does it take place?

Comment: It seems intuitively obvious to me given the director was mentioning how this is supposed to continue on from shortly after the end of the first set of movies, but I can't find a reference to that.  There is also general media reports supporting that it is Australia,  given articles like ...

Comment: .. [Red sand dunes, barren river beds and stunning scenes of the famed Skeleton Coast: Namibia **stands in as post-apocalyptic Australia** in the much-anticipated blockbuster Mad Max: Fury Road](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-3083165/Red-sand-dunes-barren-river-beds-stunning-scenes-famed-Skeleton-Coast-Namibia-stands-post-apocalyptic-Australia-anticipated-blockbuster-Mad-Max-Fury-Road.html). But unfortunately that article does not mention the sources of the information.

Comment: One of the flashback characters at or around 0:05:09, saying "You let us die" is an Aboriginal Australian. Given the small number of Aboriginal Australians among the Australian diaspora, it's very likely that the character is Australian. Couple that to the fact that he's still looking for the sea (as in hasn't seen it yet), it's rather safe to assume that *Mad Max: Fury Road* takes place in Australia.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not explicitly mentioned in the movie, but it would be safe to assume that the story takes place in Australia itself, because the character Max keeps dwelling in the Australian outbacks in the first 3 installments, which span more than 20 years. So we can tend to believe that the character's fate is to dwell in the Australian Outbacks only.

Secondly as we know that there is fuel-shortage scenario in the background of this dystopia. So traveling outside country seems less plausible. More so because Australia is an island and the nearest country New Zealand has an entirely different landscape. So taking a clue from the outdoors in this latest franchise, along with character info, we can assume that it takes place in Australia.

It might have been filmed anywhere in the world which can resemble Australia, but we have no indication in the 4th part that the story has changed its location.

Comment: I can't think of a single scene in the Mad Max films which proves that they are set in Australia.

Comment: OP has posted a link in question which states that. Wikipedia too agrees with that. In Mad Max 2 the only companions of Max are a shotgun and an Australian cattle dog

Comment: From wikipedia, Mad Max 3, Jedediah flies the children to the coast, where they discover the ruins of Sydney. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Max_Beyond_Thunderdome

Comment: Anyone can edit Wikipedia. I don't think that the city they find has any identifiable features, and certainly isn't named as Sydney, so it could be any city. The radical mixture of accents in the Mad Max films alone indicates that we have no idea where these films are set.

Comment: How about OP's link, its from IMDb. I could not open it though, I am on a VPN

Comment: IMDb does say that the first one is set in Australia, but anyone can edit that to. For the record, I do believe that *Mad Max* is set in Australia, but I don't think the same is necessarily true of the others thanks to how loose the continuity is.

Comment: @DrRDizzle *"I don't think that the city they find has any identifiable features"* From [11 Jaw-Dropping Miniature Movie Sets - Mad Max: Beyond Thunderdome](http://au.pcmag.com/gallery/36251/11-jaw-dropping-miniature-movie-sets?p=8) I (as a Sydneysider) can identify the (remains of the) Sydney Harbour Bridge on the right hand side, and even more tellingly, the 'multiple sails' of the Sydney Opera House on the left.

Comment: @AndrewThompson OK, that it a lot more evidence than I expected to see, thank you - I now agree that the city at the end of *Mad Max: Beyond Thunderdome* is Sydney. I'd still argue that we can't know for sure where *Mad Max: Fury Road* is set though - the films barely even share a continuity, as addressed in my answers on SciFi.SE [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90481/is-scrooloose-from-beyond-thunderdome-a-stranded-war-boy/90482#90482) and [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90968/in-fury-road-who-is-the-little-girl-who-torments-max/91000#91000).

Comment: @DrRDizzle  *"same actor (Bruce Spence) in very similar roles (Gyrocopter pilots) but as different characters.."*  Huh.. I'd never actually seen MM3 and known that!  (..I just found that page with an image of the set based on Ankit's statement about 'Sydney ruined city'.)

Comment: Not relevant to the answer @Ankit, but both Indonesia and Papua New Guinea are closer to Australia than New Zealand is.

Answer (score 3):

**We don't have enough information to be sure** - at least, not from the film itself.

No character in *Mad Max: Fury Road* mentions they are, other than through reference to the 5 named places we get in *Mad Max: Fury Road*. These places are;

- The Citadel (stronghold of Immortan Joe)
- Gas Town (stronghold of The People Eater)
- The Bullet Farm (stronghold of the Bullet Farmer)
- The Green Place (home of the Vuvalini/the Many Mothers)
- The Salt (implied to be a dried up seabed)

None of these places seem to be references to real world locations other than The Salt, and even that doesn't give us any information about the real world location of *Mad Max: Fury Road* other than it is meant to be within a couple of days driving distance to an ocean.